# Loading more links in a page after sending json requests in Python

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, infinite-scroll

I am parsing this [URL](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/xom) to get links from one of the boxes with infinite scroll. Here is mo code for sending the requests for the website to get next 10 links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib
import extraction
import json
from json2html import *

baseUrl = 'http://www.marketwatch.com/news/headline/getheadlines'
parameters2 = {
'ticker':'XOM',
'countryCode':'US',
'docType':'2007',
'sequence':'6e09aca3-7207-446e-bb8a-db1a4ea6545c',
'messageNumber':'1830',
'count':'10',
'channelName':'',
'topic':' ',
'_':'1479539628362'}
html2 = requests.get(baseUrl, params = parameters2)
html3 = json.loads(html2.text) # array of size 10
```

In the corresponding HTML , there is an element like:

```
 <li class="loading">Loading more headlines...</li>
```

that tells there are more items to be loaded by scrolling dowwn , but I don't know how to use json file to write a loop to gets more links. 
My first try was to use Beautiful Soup and to write the following code to get links and ids  :

```
url = 'http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/xom' 
r = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
pressReleaseBox = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'prheadlines'})
```

and then check if there is more link to scrape, get the next json file:

```
loadingMore = pressReleaseBox.find('li',attrs={'class':'loading'})
while loadingMore != None:
    # get the links from json file and load more links
```

I don't know hot to implement the comment part. do you have any idea about it?
I am not obliged to use BeautifulSoup, and any other working library will be fine.

Comment: I'd do another approach: Open the website, open your browser's devtools and switch to the "network" tab, then on the page scroll down until it loads more headlines. Watch your devtool's network tab, you'll see some requests to another URL. You can play with the date/time parameter of that URL to retrieve the headlines, and it'll come out as JSON (even easier to parse than HTML).

Comment: Thank U chrki, that seems an interesting alternative, but I have no idea how to work with date/time to scrape data, as ''messageNumber'' changes for each news scrolled page and it counts down by "count": "10". If I get data for 3 years, I am done, and your idea is nice, but could you guide me how to implement it please?

Comment: Even if I removed the date/time parameter, json file would not be changed !!!

Comment: Basically: Retrieve the JSON file, look for the oldest date and time, and insert that date and time into the 2nd request. Then repeat that over and over until you've reached the limit of what you need. You can also change the `&count=` parameter in the URL to something higher, say 100, to retrieve more news at a time. I might take a look later. **Edit:** Or change one of the other parameters, you are right changing the date does nothing. Someone posted an answer.

Comment: Thank you chrki, I am going to implement the answer and also take your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can load more json file:

1. get last json file, extract value of key `UniqueId` in last item.

   1. if the value is something looks like `e5a00f51-8821-4fbc-8ac6-e5f64b5eb0f2:8499`

      1. extract `e5a00f51-8821-4fbc-8ac6-e5f64b5eb0f2` as `sequence`
      2. extract `8499` as `messageNumber`
      3. let `docId` be empty
   2. if the value is something looks like `1222712881`

      1. let `sequence` be empty
      2. let `messageNumber` be empty
      3. extract `1222712881` as `docId`
2. put parameters `sequence`, `messageNumber`, `docId` into your parameters2.
3. use `requests.get(baseUrl, params = parameters2)` to get your next json file.

Comment: @Anyanyn: Thank you very much, it seems to work well, I'll implement it.

Comment: I followed your clear hints, I get the first json file but the problem is that when I change docId, messagNumber or any other key, the output is exactly same and I cannot send the next request to get new links. Do I do anything wrong?

Comment: @farshidbalan from the HTML page, there are `<li>` nodes which contain `data-uniqueid` attribute. Its value is from `UniqueId`, so extract its value to initialize `sequence` and `messageNumber`, or `docId`. And set `channelName` to `/news/latest/company/us/xom`. I had successfully gotten json files, if you still could not make it, just ask me for code.

Comment: @ Anyany: I deeply appreciate your help. Thanks to your kind help,  I could get the next json by changing the messageNumber. After 4 requests, all requests use only docId. I am new to programming and I don't know after sending the first json(with docId ) and getting response, how to extract the new docId (as they seem to be random in each request) and then send another request. As docId only exists inside the HTML file and I have no idea how to connect HTML to json .

Comment: @ Anyany: I also asked the question in stackoverflow, may some other people have similar problems :)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780492/gettin-html-element-and-sending-new-json-requests-in-python

Comment: @farshidbalan i have post my completed solution to your problem. hope it help.