# Gettin HTML element and sending new json requests in python

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I try to  crawl [this link](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/xom) by sending json requests. My first request would be :

```
parameters1 = {'ticker':'XOM', 'countryCode':'US',
       'dateTime':'', 'docId':'1222737422 ',
       'docType':'806','sequence':'e5a00f51-8821-4fbc-8ac6-e5f64b5eb0f2',
       'messageNumber':'','count':'10',
      'channelName':'/news/latest/company/us/xom', 'topic':'',
       '_':'' }
firstUrl = "http://www.marketwatch.com/news/headline/getheadlines"
html1 = requests.get(firstUrl, params = parameters1, headers = header)
html_json1=(json.loads(html1.text))
```

for sending the next requests, I have to extract docId from the corresponding HTML and add it to the new parameters. I don't know how to do that. Do you have any idea how to get new HTML frile after sending json requestes?

Comment: what does html_json1 has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


def main():

    html_url = 'http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/xom'

    resp = requests.get(html_url)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("http request failed: %s" % resp)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

    # get value of `data-uniqueid` from last news node of 'MarketWatch News on XOM'
    li_node = soup.select("#mwheadlines > div.headlinewrapper > ol > li[data-uniqueid]")[-1]
    unique_id = li_node['data-uniqueid']
    print('got unique_id=%r, from %r' % (unique_id, li_node.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip()))


    baseUrl = 'http://www.marketwatch.com/news/headline/getheadlines'
    parameters = {
        'ticker':'XOM',
        'countryCode':'US',
        'docType':'806',
        'docId': '', # (Optional) initial value extract from HTML page
        'sequence':'e5a00f51-8821-4fbc-8ac6-e5f64b5eb0f2', # initial value extract from HTML page
        'messageNumber':'8589', # initial value extract from HTML page
        'count':'10',
        'channelName': '/news/latest/company/us/xom',
    }

    parameters.update(extract_page_params(unique_id))


    while True:
        resp = requests.get(baseUrl, params = parameters)
        data = json.loads(resp.text) # array of size 10 
        first = data[0] # get first item of array
        last = data[-1] # get last item of array
        print("\ngot %d data, url: %s" % (len(data), resp.url))
        print("\tfirst: %-42s, %s" % (first['UniqueId'], first['SeoHeadlineFragment']))
        print("\t last: %-42s, %s" % (last['UniqueId'], last['SeoHeadlineFragment']))
        print("")


        uid = last['UniqueId'] # get value of UniqueId from dict object `last`

        parameters.update(extract_page_params(uid))

        input("press <enter> to get next")


def extract_page_params(uid):
    sequence = ''
    messageNumber = ''

    docId = ''

    if ':' in uid: # if the symbol ':' in string `uid`
        # uid looks like `e5a00f51-8821-4fbc-8ac6-e5f64b5eb0f2:8499`
        # so split it by ':'
        sequence, messageNumber = uid.split(':')
    else:
        docId = uid

    return {
        'sequence': sequence,
        'messageNumber': messageNumber,
        'docId': docId,
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my code to solve your problem.
Since you are new to programming, i have added some comments.
You could directly copy and run with python version 3. (2 should work either)

Comment: OK, my gmail is panyanyany ## gmail dot com. Feel free to contact me. ;-) @farshidbalan

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to extract data from html.It is a python library for extracting data from HTML.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to do it with BeautifulSOup.